# Database Design for the following Scenario

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, database-design

I am working on creating a database schema for the following Requirements: 
Employees have certain attributes. These same attributes are found on jobs. 
What I need to be able to do is search for employees based on a given job's attributes. For example, "Find me all employees that match job id = 1 and have the same attributes for it". (vice Versa for Searching for all jobs for a given employee). Here is my database schema.

```
Job (
   jobId, 
   description
)

Employee(
  employeeId, 
  firstName, 
  lastName,
  startDate,
  email
)

Attribute(
   attributeId,
   description       
)

JobAttribute(
  jobId, (FK to Jobs.jobId)
  attributeId (FK to Attributes.attributeId)
)

EmployeeAttribute(
   employeeId, (FK to Employees.employeeId)
   attributeId (FK to Attributes.attributeId).       
)
```

Query for "Find me all employees that match job id = 1 and have the same attributes for it".  would then look like :

```
SELECT DiSTINCT e.employeeId 
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN EmployeeAttribute ea
ON e.attributeId = ea.AttributeId
and e.employeeId = ea.employeeId
WHERE ea.AttributeId In (
Select ja.attributeId 
FROM Job j
inner join JobAttribute ja
    on j.jobId = ja.jobId
inner join AttributeTable at
    on ja.attributeId = at.attributeId
where jobId = 1
)
order by e.startDate asc
```

The query would return all employees that have at least one attribute the same as the job.

How would the query look like if I need to return all employees that have ALL attributes assigned to them as per the jobs using this schema?

Is this good design for query performance. I also want to make this as flexible as possible to allow new attributes to be added with minimal code change.

Comment: Table names should be singular; Employee table holds 0 or more tuples.

Comment: @duffymo that is purely a matter of preference. I would disagree. A table is intended to be the collection of tuples. Thus the collection (table name) would be plural but the column names would be singular. That being said I don't quite understand your comment because the names posted are singular.

Comment: What you have here is known as EAV (entity attribute value). There are lots of people around who think this type of pattern is the most evil thing ever. I think this pattern has its place and is quite useful in the right situation. One of the downsides to this type of pattern is causes you to join to the attribute tables repeatedly to get all the values.

Comment: You may want to translate your requirements into an ER diagram which will bring out entities and their relationship clearly, this in turn will help identify what becomes a table, derived table and their relationship etc.., In your question, there could be a link between Employees and Jobs without going via attributes - if thats the case the design would change.

Comment: in my requirements, employees are only linked to jobs if they have the attribute associated to them of that job. so a employee id in the jobs as a FK will not be feasible. :(

Comment: Your question is unclear - Are you looking for a list of employees, each of whom have all possible attributes associated with them that all possible jobs have associated with them in the entire database? Are you looking for a list of employees who satisfy all tags associated with a given jobId, and return the Employee/JobID combination? A bit more specificity is required here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your first query, "Find me all employees that match job id = 1 and have the same attributes for it", could be simpler as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EmployeeId
FROM 
Employee E
INNER JOIN EmployeeAttribute EA ON (EA.EmpId = E.EmployeeId)
INNER JOIN JobAttribute JA ON (EA.AttributeId = JA.AttributeId)
WHERE AJ.JobId = 1
```

on your query on retrieving employees matching all attributes for a given job

```
SELECT EA.EmployeeId, COUNT(EA.EmployeeId)
FROM EmployeeAttribute EA
INNER JOIN JobAttribute JA on EA.AttributeId = JA.AttributeId
WHERE JA.JobId = @jobId
GROUP BY EA.EmployeeId
HAVING COUNT(EA.EmployeeId) >= (SELECT COUNT(AttributeId) FROM JobAttribute J where J.JobId = @jobId)
```

You may have to join with Employee master to get other details of the employee. Both the queries assume that there is a PK on the derived tables which is a combination of both FKs.

In terms of performance, use the query execution plan and define your indexes accordingly.